# Convert ID to Int and save to datatable

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have been trying to add the Customer_ID from the Customer table to Customer_ID in Customer_Ship table.  I keep running into the Customer_ID not converting to Int properly.  It's possible that I am not actually getting the new row added to Customer_Ship table first.  Your help is greatly appreciated and many thanks in advance.

```
    if (customer_ID == "")
    {
    string SQL = "INSERT INTO Customer (Customer_Name) VALUES (@customer_Name); SELECT Customer_ID FROM Customer WHERE Customer_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlConnection);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@customer_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = customer_Name;

    sqlConnection.Open();
    int customer_Id = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

    SQL = "INSERT INTO Customer_Ship (Customer_ID) VALUES (@customer_Id)";
    sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlConnection);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddwithValue("@customer_Id", customer_Id);
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _not converting to Int properly_? You get any exception or error message?

Comment: I get an Unhandled exception of type, sorry for not being specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes I see:

1. you should be just returning `SCOPE_IDENTITY` - you can simplify your first `INSERT` statement to read:

   ```
   INSERT INTO Customer (Customer_Name) VALUES (@customer_Name); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
   ```

   This **will** return the newly inserted `Customer_ID` identity value from the `Customer` table - no need to do this complicated `SELECT` that you had in your question
2. You need to call `.ExecuteScalar()` right from the beginning - don't call `.ExecuteNonQuery()` first and then `ExecuteScalar()` - that'll execute the statement **twice** - just use:

   ```
   using(SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlConnection))
   {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@customer_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = customer_Name;

        sqlConnection.Open();
        int customer_Id = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        sqlConnection.Close();
   }
   ```

   That'll insert the values into `Customer` and return the newly created `Customer_ID` as the return value into `customer_id` (which already **is** an `Int`) from `.ExecuteScalar()`. You can then use this `int` value to insert into the `Customer_Ship` table - no conversion necessary - this already is an `int`

Comment: Thanks Marc_s, I worked thru this and have fixed my problems with your help.  I have modified the original code post to show the working code.  I hope this will also help others.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason for not converting the value is you are trying to convert an empty string(***customer_ID*** : Refer Line :#1 of your code) and not ***"customer_Id "*** what you are fetching from the database .